# EXTJS textfield (HH:MM AM/PM) format with validation

Tags: extjs

I am stuck with the situation where i have to display HH:MM AM/PM in textField(EXTJS) ... and it should take the data in 12 hour format .... and should not take values apart from this can anybody help please ....

Answer (score 1):

You can use a TimeField of ExtJs.Form namespace and the default format of the field is what you are looking for.

URL: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.TimeField